# Propositional pro-forms like "so" English?

Tags: list-of-languages, anaphora, pro-forms

I'm looking for examples of **dedicated embedding pro-forms for propositions** in other languages. In particular, I'm curious to know about analogs to uses of *so* in English like the following:

1. I think so.

Obviously, *so* has many other uses in English. But I'm only interested in uses where it appears as an argument to attitude verbs like *think*. I'm also not interested in embedded event pro-forms. *So* can play this role in English, but it is subtly different than (1). We see it here:

2. I want to do so.

Finally, I'm not interested in normal pronouns acting as embedded pro-forms for propositions. In English, *it* and *that* can both do this:

3. I think {it/that}.

But these pronouns are not dedicated embedding pro-forms for propositions like the use of *so* in (1).

In short, I want to know if other languages have expressions similar to *so* that are not pronouns and can be used to anaphorically reference a proposition.

Comment: Russian так (so) acts the same way as the English _so_ in your examples 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of any discussion on the semantics of так?

Comment: [Wiktionary has it](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA), see the meaning of так in the Slavic languages there.

Comment: In Dutch `Dat denk ik wel` = I indeed think that = [that] [think] [I] [indeed]

Comment: I'm curious, @pdve, did my answer make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

In some major European languages:

Russian: *Я **так** думаю.* or *Думаю, **да**.*
(Note: the comma here may be correct but it does not represent a pause when speaking.)

Dutch: *Dat denk ik **wel**.*

German: *Ich denke **schon**.*
(See [this](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schon#Antwortpartikel))

Italian: *Credo **di si**.*

Spanish: *Creo/pienso **que sí**.*
But you should also look at the use of *sí* as an intensifying adverb (eg *Yo **sí** creo/pienso*).

In the case of *wel*, *schon* and *sí*, the word in question is, in other situations, the translation of the English word *indeed* and/or emphatic *do*.

(As a side note, in English one could say *I do indeed think.* to mean that one thinks in general, but in German it would end up likewise *Ich denke schon.*, similarly for Spanish.)

The above translations assume the emphasis in *I think so.* is on *so*.
But the translation depends on the emphasis:

**i. emphasis on *think*:**
In this case English only changes the intonation (from *so* to *think*), but the other languages can drop that word, leaving only *(I) think.* I believe in English *so* is nearly obligatory in that case.

**ii. emphasis on *I*:**
Dropping the word is again generally optional in the other languages in this case, but not in English.

**iii. *I think so too*:**
Similarly *I think so too.* in others can just be *I think too.* or *I too think.* (or *Think too I.* etc).

**iv. negation:**
In negation, English can still use *so* (eg *I don't think so.*).  The others cannot, they end up more like *I think not.* / *I don't think* / *I think no.*.

Definitely read about German [*doch*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doch#German), as it likewise can stand in for entire sentences.

So I see no equivalent with full coverage.  The combination of ways English handles emphasis and negation and implied objects is unique among its closest relatives.

Answer (score 0):

Russian analog of English ***so*** is ***так***. It can be used almost everywhere where you use ***so***.

> I think so = Я думаю так
>
> I want to do so = Я хочу сделать так
>
> They are so many = Их так много
>
> He is so smart = Он такой умный.
>
> So, no = Так что, нет.

Comment: imho Я так думаю sounds much more natural.

Comment: @Alex B. depends on the meaning. Я думаю так is an answer on the your interlocutor's expressed position, a confirmation.

Comment: Could you give me an example where "Я думаю так" would sound more natural? I'm sorry but it rubs me the wrong way and if someone wrote it, I'd correct them. (NB: I didn't say it's impossible at all, but I need examples.)

Comment: @Alex B. Что, он прямо после убийства пошел есть в ресторан? - Я думаю, так. Or Почему он ещё не решил эту задачу? - Это очень сложная проблема для него, я думаю так. In the second case я так думаю is appropriate, but underlines думаю, while я думаю так underlines так.

Comment: I don't know, imho your examples sound extremely unnatural. I'd never say it nor have I ever heard it before. Your examples sound as if they were translated by Google or written by someone whose L1 is English and now they're studying Russian.

Comment: The only possible way when "я думаю так" is acceptable is when you are going to explain your opinion (in more detail), e.g. Я думаю так: ....... . The Russian National Corpus confirms my **native speaker intuition**. "Я думаю так, если ты футболист, то и играй в футбол, если ты модель, снимайся!"(2005) or "Я думаю так: если масса людей делает что-то в едином порыве ― это совсем не значит, что они правы." (2003)

Comment: @Alex B. I disagree.

Comment: Disagree with what? Also, could you tell me more about your background, if possible (age group, what part of Russia, L1 or L2, in case you're bilingual, education). Just curious.

Comment: @Alex B. Moscow, 35, not bilingual, university education.